# Possible to set max-height on an element with position fixed just once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a sidebar (id="sidebar") set up with position=fixed on the top right hand corner.

The issue is when the window height is smaller than the sidebar, I want the sidebar to have a scrollbar. Currently, I have a function where I am setting max-height, called by window.resize as well as in some other places:

```
$("#sidebar").css("max-height", window.innerHeight - 15);
```

This is working, and the scrollbar appears and works as it should when I resize my window smaller than the sidebar. My question is: Is there possibly a way where I could avoid having to set max-height on every resize event, and instead calling something once on setup and still get the same scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JS for this. Use CSS:

`#sidebar {max-height:calc(100vh - 15px)}`